# MonoTouch and iPhone static libraries

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

Does MonoTouch allow to create iPhone static libraries? If yes how it can be done?

Comment: go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604033/is-monotouch-now-banned-on-the-iphone

Comment: I would also like to know if MonoTouch can create a native static library for iOS, instead of an application. Did you ever find out?

Comment: Not directly an answer, but this will allow you to call MonoTouch code from Objective-c: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522260/is-there-a-way-to-mix-monotouch-and-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

New Project -> C# -> MonoTouch -> MonoTouch Library Project