# Developing Monotouch and XCode in parallel - how to set it up

Tags: xcode, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xcode3.2

Would it make sense to develop an app in Monotouch and With XCOde in parallel or with Monotouch as a prototype.  (I would be learning both while developing).

Since both use the same interface-builder.  Could I just take the files and create a SDK version from the same interface files the same way just after?

How can I set it up so that I share as much as possible (Locally and/or source control).

What should I use of test-tools etc?  (So that I can share my tests?)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522260/is-there-a-way-to-mix-monotouch-and-objective-c