# Calling MonoTouch Library from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, mono, xamarin.ios

I am using [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522260/is-there-a-way-to-mix-monotouch-and-objective-c) as a guide to call into a MonoTouch library from within an Objective-C application. We have an existing iPhone application and an existing c# library which we need to bring together. We have considered re-writing the iPhone app (Objective-C) in MonoTouch, but we do not have the time right now. We need a way to use our MonoTouch library from the iPhone/Objective-C app.

My problem is, the Xcode project generated by calling `mtouch` cannot be compiled. It cannot find the mono header files and the .s files referenced by the project are not found because they are instead named with a .6.s extension. Am I running `mtouch` incorrectly? If not, how can I tell the Xcode project where the mono header files are located so it can compile? Also, how can I set up the Objective-C code to call my MonoTouch library (the main.m file has some clues, but it does not appear to be straight-forward)?

Here are the type of errors:

> error: mono/jit/jit.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I resolved the no such file or directory errors by adding a path to the header files in the project properties, but I am still seeing an endless list of errors during compilation.