# How do I translate monotouch code to xcode

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I have an app written in MONOTOUCH. It works- I tested it with TESTFLIGHT. It is being added to a larger app, and that developer needs the full xcode project. Do I need to have it rewritten or is there a way to convert it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a MonoTouch license, you can use `mtouch --xcode yourapp.exe` to generate Objective-C code. It doesn't work in the evaluation version.

Much more detail is available in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522260/is-there-a-way-to-mix-monotouch-and-objective-c/2081307#2081307).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to convert Mono code to Objective-C code.

There is an --xcode option that may or may not work.   It has not been maintained and we do not officially support it, so I would not depend on it working.

My suggestion is to keep the two applications separate, and transfer control from one to the other by using urls.   You register two url handlers "firstApp:" and "secondApp:" and when you need to go from the first to the second, you issue a Url open to "SecondApp:statevariables" and the same process is repeated to go back.