# Is there a way to make a native cocoa class library in MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, class-library

I know that MonoTouch compiles code down to native machine code. Is there anyway to make a native (.a) class library using MonoTouch? Just to be clear, I'm not looking to share code between the two since I know that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be possible, but it would be hard work, and it's a long way from shrink-wrapped out-of-the-box functionality.

For reference, take a look through the answers on [Is there a way to mix MonoTouch and Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522260/is-there-a-way-to-mix-monotouch-and-objective-c) - that question is about how to bootstrap and then call into mt from an obj-c application. I think the same approach would just about work for a .a library.

Comment: Just in case my answer is unclear... I say that I think this might be possible... I didn't say I'd recommend trying it! Seems like a world of pain!

Comment: My end goal is to see if I can create a jailbreak tweak for the iPhone with all of my logic in a class library created by monotouch.