# Xamarin free edition and Deployment Jailbroken iPhone 7x possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, deployment, xamarin, jailbreak

I just started developing for the iPhone with Xamarin free. I have the free edition and I don't have an Apple Development license.

Is it possible to jailbreak my iPhone 5s and deploy on the jailbroken iPhone? I read somewhere that it will be difficult because of Cydia.

And can I deploy with the free edition?

Tnx!

Comment: Do you want to develop *jailbreak* tweaks or utilites or do you just want to know if you can develop on a device that has been jailbroken?

Answer (score 0):

I do Xamarin development (with the business license but that doesn't matter) on my jailbroken iPhone 5s on iOS 7.0.6 with no problems.

However, if you are asking if you can develop jailbreak tweaks with the xamarin tools, that is a different thing. I want to know that exact thing so I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805211) here but didn't really find a good solution. You would have to compile it to a library (not an application) that your tweak would reference. Your other problem is that you would probably want to use a private API that Xamarin doesn't expose/wrap.

Xamarin, now, allows you to deploy to device with the Starter edition as long as the app is below a certain size.

Lastly, this is probably the biggest killer for you, you can't deploy to your device without being in the apple developer program. You need to have certificates to sign your builds and make publishing profiles to allow your phone to run ad-hoc/debug builds which can only be made through apple's dev site. This is also where you can register your device(s) as a testing device.

Comment: Yes I would like to know if it is possible to deploy on a jailbroken iphone without paying for the apple license.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You need to enroll in the program to be able to sign the application. Without that, I don't think that Xcode, Xamarin Studio, or Visual Studio will build the application.

Comment: @valdetero [its possible for XCode](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#How_to_test_your_app_on_your_iOS_device_without_being_a_member_of_the_Apple_Developer_program_.28New_.26_Simple.29), so it should be possible for Xamarin too.