# Mono + Xcode: How to author a library in C# using Xamarin Studio, and consume it in a CocoaTouch project within Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mono, cross-platform, xamarin-studio

For an iOS app that will eventually be ported to Android/Winphone, I would love to be able to write some re-usable libraries in c#, but author the iOS UI in traditional Obj-C and reference the library written in c# from Xcode and consume it from Obj-C.

I've found lots of docs that talk about going the other way via bindings (Obj-C -> C#), but not much pertaining to my question.  Also, a similar question was asked 4 years ago here, but a lot has changed in the ecosystem, the info seems out of date, and some of the links in the answers now redirect elsewhere:

- [Is there a way to mix MonoTouch and Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522260/is-there-a-way-to-mix-monotouch-and-objective-c)

So, is this possible?  If so how, and what's the best way to achieve it today? (Or alternately, is this a bad idea and should be abandoned?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible to consume a C# library from Objective-C.

Note that it is usually possible to do it the other way with some ingenuity - the only real requirement is that the app must be a Xamarin.iOS app and the entry point the managed Main method. In your Main method you can call into native (C/Objective-C) code and have all your logic there.

Comment: So just to confirm then, there's no way to compile any project type within Xamarin Studio down to a binary (.a file or otherwise) that can then be referenced and consumed via an Obj-C project in XCode?  And was this possible at some point in the past (as the answers in that old SO post seemed to indicate) and now longer is?

Either way, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Correct, there is no way to produce a binary (.a or otherwise) from a Xamarin.iOS project that can be consumed in an Obj-C project in Xcode. It was technically possible in the past (quite difficult, tedious and error-prone, yet still possible), but in any case it has never been officially supported.